# How do I use a Form to fill 28 entries at once

Tags: ms-access

I have to make an audience form that will display all the students on the list, and you go through the form and change the status of the student to absent, present, etc. I need to create a screen that will have the names, date, id, and status. The form is not supposed to edit existing data, but it is supposed to just have the student names already in the form. and when I save the form it should populate the attendance page with 28 new data entries for that date. Most of the data (from what I understand) is present in the form and I would just use a selection box to pick the status of the student.  I have the date set to just go to today's date as that's all the teacher would use.

I've tried what I can but I don't know enough about Access to have done anything close. I've made a form that displays the names, but I can only do one entry at a time. Any help would be appreciated, images are included below. I also have other tables in the database but none are related to this post

[image: DB_page]

[image: Auto_form]

[image: Slow_Entry]

Comment: Names are all made up except mine

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish this task, and it will likely take some coding to produce a convenient form as you desire.  As it stands, this request is too broad and so is off topic for Stackoverflow.  Consider narrowing your request and describing desired behavior in more detail to avoid the question being close.  Of course taking attendance for individuals should probably require marking them one-by-one.  What is meant by "do"-ing an entry?  You need to clearly explain the desired behavior.

Comment: One hint about proper table normalization.  It looks like you already have a `Student` table that I assume contains the `Student_ID` and name columns.  You should not store the names in the Attendance table, only the single foreign-key column `Student_ID` which refers back to the other table.  (The idea of normalization is to avoid duplicate data which can waste storage and create contradictory edits and complicate maintenance.)

Answer (score 0):

So your question concerns how to batch create student records in Attendance table for particular date. This is often accomplished with an INSERT SELECT action SQL.

`CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Attendance([Day], Student_ID) SELECT Date(), Student_ID FROM Students"`

The SELECT subquery can include a WHERE clause if needed.

Set the Day and Student_ID fields as unique compound index in table to prevent duplicate pairs.

Apply filter to the form to display only current date records and/or Attendance field Is Null.

The real trick is figuring out what event to put code into - most likely a button click on a form.

Day is a reserved word (it is a function) and should not use reserved words as names for anything.